# How can I add a Details screen to the LightSwitch menu?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a UserSettings entity.  Each user will have one and only one row in the table.  I'd like to give users a menu group called Settings containing a menu item called User Settings which opens a Details screen on their row, so that they can edit their own settings.  I don't want them to see a list of UserSettings, even though I could filter it to just their row because it doesn't look good.

I've read that you can only add a screen to a menu if the screen doesn't have parameters.  I can remove the UserSettingsId parameter from a new Details screen for UserSettings and it appears in the Include Screen drop-down on the Screen Navigation tab but I can't set the UserSettings object for the screen in code because it's read-only.

Is there any way for the user to go straight to a edit screen, without selecting the item to be edited from a list?

I'm using VS LightSwitch 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the in-built security model, you should be able to interrogate the User object (which is a child object of the Application object).  This can be used to populate a screen variable for the user name based on a look up at run-time which you can then pass to a Query on your Settings table based on UserID or UserName as appropriate.

HTH